# Check if a column value is updated to NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have to determine if a column has been updated from a NOT NULL value to NULL in sql server.

Example -

```
UpdateDate                         Value      Individual
2020-09-02 10:39:03.530            NULL       105292933 
2020-08-31 11:05:06.053            Y          105292933
2020-08-31 11:04:32.720            N          105292931
```

In above example, for Individual 105292933, Value has been updated to NULL from Y. So the result should be the first row. I am new to sql server. Here is what I tried to get the result -

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableX AS a
WHERE a.Value <>
      ( SELECT TOP 1 b.Value
        FROM tableX AS b
        WHERE a.Individual = b.Individual
        AND a.UpdateDate > b.UpdateDate
        ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
      )
```

But it is not picking the changes from Y to NULL or N to NULL. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare a value with NULL, You can only compare something that is (strings, numbers etc).

In SQL Server `NULL != NULL`. To check if value is null use `WHERE a.value IS NULL`

You can change Your code to compare column with some special string (or empty string if You like) if its value is NULL using `ISNULL()` function.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM tableX AS a
WHERE ISNULL(a.Value, '*NULL*') <>
      ( SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(b.Value, '*NULL*')
        FROM tableX AS b
        WHERE a.Individual = b.Individual
        AND a.UpdateDate > b.UpdateDate
        ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
      )
```

A litter more about NULL values here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are usually more efficient than subqueries, when applicable. I would recommend `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(value) over(partition by individual order by updatedate) lag_value
    from mytable t
) t
where value is null and lag_value is not null
```

Comment: @SiddharthUbana: *did not work* is not a helpful comment. Please explain what is wrong with the result that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This query identifies rows were the prior value (based on UpdateDate) was 'Y' or 'N'.  Something like this

```
with lag_cte as (
    select *, lag([value]) over(partition by individual order by updatedate) lag_value
    from tableX)
select *
from lag_cte
where value is null 
      and lag_value in('N', 'Y');
```

Comment: I need to select the row which has Value changed from N or Y to NULL for a particular Individual

Comment: Updated please review